# Postgresql order by case when {someCase} then json type column

Tags: postgresql

I need order result from select by few ways.
It's working when it's some column from table TenderItem.
But NOT working if it some key from json type column TenderItem.ItemInfo, f.e.

> select  * from "TenderItem" order by "ItemInfo" ->> 'Name'; -- working in simple select

```
with sortingParams (columnName, isAsc) AS (VALUES ('ItemId', true))
select *
FROM "TenderItem" i, sortingParams
WHERE i."TenderId" = 1
AND  i."ItemInfo" ->> 'Name' like '%Transcend%'
ORDER BY
case
WHEN columnName like '%ItemId%' THEN i."ItemId" --*work
WHEN columnName like '%ABCSegment%' THEN i."ItemInfo" ->> 'ABCSegment' --**
end desc;
```

**on this string i have message "ERROR: CASE types bigint and text cannot be matched"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how you'd sort the itemID against the ItemInfo segment (unless this points to an item id) since they are not all text values (and if they are all text but some are text strings like '12345' then you do not want to use text sort since then '100' would come before '99'). You probably want them to be separate sort conditions to give more flexibility in ordering:

```
with sortingParams (columnName, isAsc) AS (VALUES ('ItemId', true))
select *
FROM "TenderItem" i, sortingParams
WHERE i."TenderId" = 1
AND  i."ItemInfo" ->> 'Name' like '%Transcend%'
ORDER BY
case
WHEN columnName like '%ItemId%' THEN i."ItemId"::bigint end asc nulls last --puts things with an itemID ahead of those without, or could use nulls first
--if two items have same item id, then sort by segment
, case  
WHEN columnName like '%ABCSegment%' THEN i."ItemInfo" ->> 'ABCSegment' 
end desc;
```

Note that each sort condition must give the same datatype for each row being evaluated! This is what gives the error your described where the case statement gives a biting for ItemId and a text value for `ItemInfo ->> 'ABCSegment'`

Answer (score 0):

ItemId is `BIGINT` and `i."ItemInfo" ->> 'ABCSegment'` is text which are incompatible types to do sorting on.

Try casting the value explicitly to `BIGINT`, i.e

```
..WHEN columnName like '%ABCSegment%' THEN (i."ItemInfo" ->> 'ABCSegment')::BIGINT
```

or make i."ItemId" a text if the above fails due to invalid `bigint` values.

```
i."ItemId"::TEXT
```